# Android App and Google App Engine/Cloud SQL

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

After looking over the documentation for Google App Engine and trying to figure out how to integrate an Android App to use the service I have come to a point where I am stuck. Just looking for some clarification here.

**What is the difference between an Google App Engine App, and the Android App itself?**

I am confused as to what it means by **deploying** an app to the App Engine.

**Does this mean that the app deployed to the App Engine contains the different API's used to retrieve data from the Android Client or what?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android app lives on the phone. The GAE app lives on Google's servers.

Android doesn't have direct access to your project's database, since that also lives on Google's servers. The GAE app listens to API calls made over the Internet from your Android app, and returns data which the Android app can then use.

Deploying a GAE app means uploading it to Google's servers so that it can serve your data.

Comment: Okay. So you would choose to write the GAE App in Java, PHP, Python etc.. and deploy them on the GAE. Then you make requests from the Android App to the GAE using those predefined methods to transfer the data?

Comment: Now when you create a back end using the Google plugin features found in eclipse, should you place all API's that you create within that "yourappname-Backend" folder that is created? Once you are done, you can than deploy the ""yourappname-Backend" folder?

Comment: Please ask this as a new question.